# How to override views template preprocess function of other module

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am using [Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid) module in a project.

This module uses a preprocess function like `template_preprocess_views_view_responsive_grid()`.

Now I am trying to override it by either of following way:

`MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_responsive_grid()` in `template.php`

**OR**

`MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view_responsive_grid()` in `mymodule.module`

**Problem:**

It is not overriding. Is there any other way?

I am using Drupal 7.51 and Views 3.0.

Comment: You did constantly clear the cache, right?

Comment: yes, I had cleared it.

Comment: So, when having the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module enabled and do a `dpm('HELLO')` inside your functions there is no output on the front-end of your view?

Comment: no output is giving

Comment: you have something wrong, @leymannx comments are rigth. have you a subtheme? doble check what you have.